# Create Row Number based column and repeating for another

Tags: postgresql

I want to create Row Number by Column based on each Product ID and back to 1 for another Product ID.

| Pack ID | Product ID | Row Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | P001 | 1 |
| A002 | P001 | 2 |
| A003 | P001 | 3 |
| A004 | P002 | 1 |
| A005 | P002 | 2 |
| A006 | P003 | 1 |
| A007 | P004 | 1 |
| A008 | P004 | 2 |

What query should I write ?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROW_NUMBER window function (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)).

```
select pack_id
     , product_id
     , row_number() over (partition by product_id
                              order by pack_id)    "row number"
  from test;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=55c18f7a5c91404b619460fecfd99a04).